# Can't add margins to RadioButtons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-radiogroup

I have a problem with my layout. I have a Dialog in which I would like to put RadioButtons, but as you can see on the screenshot they are really close to each other. How to widen the space between them? I've already tried Margin Left/Right, Padding Left/Right, etc, but none of this works.

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

#### My .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat_reversed" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ml_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/size"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup  android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rws"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:button="@null"
            android:text="@string/sw"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rwm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:button="@null"
            android:text="@string/mw"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rwb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:button="@null"
            android:text="@string/bw"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/percent_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/percentage"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <NumberPicker 
        android:id="@+id/percent_picker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try padding instead of margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio buttons are placed side-by-side in a `LinearLayout`. They have their `layout_width` set to `wrap_content`. The parent (the `RadioGroup`) is also set to `wrap_content`, and its two parents (`LinearLayout`, and its parent, the root `LinearLayout` element) are also set to `wrap_content`. The gravity is also set to be centred, so everything is gravitating towards the centre for the screen, and remains huddled together.

Try:

- set the root `LinearLayout` element's `layout_width` to be `fill_parent`.
- Set the nested `LinearLayout` (parent of `RadioGroup`) to be a `RelativeLayout` (i.e. change the element type)
- Set for each `RadioButton`, the width to be 33% by adding this attribute/value pair: `android:layout_weight=".33"`

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout or other Layout to Optimize the layout. You can do it like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat_reversed" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ml_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/size"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup  android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rws"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="@string/sw"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="50sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rwm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="@string/mw"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="50sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rwb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="@string/bw"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="50sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/percent_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/percentage"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/percent_picker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try it, I think it helps.